# Browser-sync don't reload HTML page automatically, need to manually reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-sync

I've been using browser-sync since last many hours and I don't know why but my HTML page don't reload automatically. I just have to reload my page manually every time

browser-sync start --server --index top-nav.html --files="css/*.css"

This is the code I'm running into my CMD, is there something wrong I'm performing into my code. I got so much frustrated after trying so many things for hours but still there is no outcome. [image: CMD screenshot]

Comment: Is your css folder in the root directory?

Comment: I notice you are using `browser-sync start --server --index top-nav.html --files="css/*.css"` which is the example from [here](https://browsersync.io/). You probably need to add the correct path to your files.

Answer (score 0):

you have to used watch option to watch every change

```
--watch, -w Watch files
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem,

```
browser-sync start --server --index top-nav.html --files="css/*.css" #Code with problem#

browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*" #Code with solution#
```

[image: Solved Problem Screenshot]